# Trying to delete a string in a list, but python wont detect it, using a csv file

Tags: python, string, list, csv, del

I am trying to delete certain elements of the beginning of my list, but when I run my code python wont detect the elements. I am currently trying to delete/find a string.

```
    my_list = [time,open,high,low,close
                1666627200,1754.7,1756.1,1750.5,1753.5]
    for i in my_list:
        my_list.remove('open')
        if i in my_list:
            print("hello")
```

The code above is everything I have tried, this was in a csv file, when my code compiles I get an error message for remove saying the element is not in the list and for the if statement, the print function is not triggered in turn meaning the if statement was false and it is not in there. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question: create a minimal example that can reproduce the error, and use code format instead of bearing your code in the text (which is especially important for Python).

Comment: Hint: print your `my_list` as its content ia not what you think it is

Comment: What are these values `1666627200,1754.7,1756.1,1750.5,1753.5` are they present in my_list? Or they are the values of `time,open,high,low,close`?

Answer (score 0):

The strings in your list need to be in quotes, otherwise Python will not know that they are strings. For example:

```
my_list = ["time","open","high","low","close", 1666627200,1754.7,1756.1,1750.5,1753.5]
```

As for using the **.remove()** method, you do not need to use a for loop since **.remove()** iterates for you. You can use the following code:

```
my_list = ["time","open","high","low","close", 1666627200,1754.7,1756.1,1750.5,1753.5]
my_list.remove("open")
print(my_list)
```

Alternatively, to check that **.remove()** actually got rid of the string "open", you can use the following for loop to check as well:

```
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

You should get the following output:

```
['time', 'high', 'low', 'close', 1666627200, 1754.7, 1756.1, 1750.5, 1753.5]
```